# How to add a new row and make it editable in jQWidgets?

Tags: javascript, jqwidget

I have a scenario where I need to add a new row to a grid, and leave it empty, but editable. I have achieved something, but it’s not quite what I’m looking for. In the example, I’ve provided a snippet of what’s happening.

I’m able to add a new row, but all the rows are editable. I only want the new row to be editable.

How can I achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
      id: "1",
      legalName: "Agrawal, Parag",
      agencyName: "Social Services",
      agencyAddress: "Market Square, 1355 Market St<br>#900<br>San Francisco, CA 94103",
      phone: "(415) 222-9670",
      hireDate: "04-3-2022",
      has401k: true
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Zuckerberg, Mark",
      agencyName: "Defense Advocates Office",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 456-1234",
      hireDate: "01-30-2019",
      has401k: true
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Walker, Johnny",
      agencyName: "Prosecutor's Office",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 329-0124",
      hireDate: "10-03-2016",
      has401k: false
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Daniels, Jack",
      agencyName: "Prosecutor's Office",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 856-5309",
      hireDate: "07-28-2011",
      has401k: false
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Fonda, Jane",
      agencyName: "Social Services",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 456-1234",
      hireDate: "06-14-2021",
      has401k: true
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Bauer, Jack",
      agencyName: "National Defense",
      agencyAddress: "24 Bauer Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 242-4242",
      hireDate: "11-10-2008",
      has401k: false
    }
  ];
  // prepare the data
  var source = {
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [{
        name: "legalName"
      },
      {
        name: "agencyName"
      },
      {
        name: "agencyAddress"
      },
      {
        name: "phone"
      },
      {
        name: "hireDate",
        type: "date"
      },
      {
        name: "has401k",
        type: "bool"
      }
    ],
    localdata: data
  };
  var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
  var source = {
    localdata: data,
    datatype: "array",
    loadComplete: function(data) {},
    loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {}
  };

  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
    source: dataAdapter,
    sortable: true,
    theme: "energyblue",
    width: "98%",
    height: "630px",
    pageable: false,
    columnsresize: true,
    selectionMode: "none",
    filterable: true,
    showfilterrow: true,
    autoheight: true,
    autorowheight: true,
    groupable: true,
    editable: true,
    columns: [{
        text: "Legal Name",
        datafield: "legalName",
        width: "20%"
      },
      {
        text: "Agency Name",
        datafield: "agencyName",
        filtertype: "checkedlist",
        width: "20%"
      },
      {
        text: "Agency Address",
        datafield: "agencyAddress",
        width: "20%"
      },
      {
        text: "Phone",
        datafield: "phone",
        width: "20%"
      },
      {
        text: "Hire Date",
        datafield: "hireDate",
        cellsformat: "d",
        filtertype: "range",
        width: "10%"
      },
      {
        text: "Has 401K",
        datafield: "has401k",
        width: "10%",
        columntype: "checkbox",
        filtertype: "checkedlist"
      }
    ]
  });

  // $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('hidecolumn', 'legalName');
});

$("#addrowbutton").jqxButton({
  theme: "energyblue",
  height: 30
});

$("#addrowbutton").on("click", function() {
  var commit = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid("addrow", null, {
    editable: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div id="jqxWidget">
  <header>
    <h2 class="text-center">Example: How to change <code>something here</code></h2>
  </header>
  <div id="jqxgrid" class="auto-margin"></div>
</div>
<p class="notice"><strong>*All data is test data only.</strong></p>

<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <input id="addrowbutton" type="button" value="Add Row" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm still in time to lend you a hand.

You can use the '***cellbeginedit***' property of '**columns**' as shown by the **editableNewRow**() function and adding a new field ***lock*** to control the editability (*you can use whatever condition as long as it suit for your edit locking purpose, here I demonstrate using **lock** field*).

In jqxGrid [API Reference](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-api.htm?search=jqxGrid), try search for 'columns' and have a look into *cellbeginedit* property.

> cellbeginedit - sets a custom function which is called when a cell
> enters into edit mode. The Grid passes 3 parameters to it - row index,
> column data field and column type. The function can be used for
> canceling the editing of a specific Grid cell. To cancel the editing,
> the function should return false.

Hope it helps !

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
      id: "1",
      legalName: "Agrawal, Parag",
      agencyName: "Social Services",
      agencyAddress: "Market Square, 1355 Market St<br>#900<br>San Francisco, CA 94103",
      phone: "(415) 222-9670",
      hireDate: "04-3-2022",
      has401k: true,
      lock: 1
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Zuckerberg, Mark",
      agencyName: "Defense Advocates Office",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 456-1234",
      hireDate: "01-30-2019",
      has401k: true,
      lock: 1
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Walker, Johnny",
      agencyName: "Prosecutor's Office",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 329-0124",
      hireDate: "10-03-2016",
      has401k: false,
      lock: 1
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Daniels, Jack",
      agencyName: "Prosecutor's Office",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 856-5309",
      hireDate: "07-28-2011",
      has401k: false,
      lock: 1
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Fonda, Jane",
      agencyName: "Social Services",
      agencyAddress: "1 Hacker Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 456-1234",
      hireDate: "06-14-2021",
      has401k: true,
      lock: 1
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      legalName: "Bauer, Jack",
      agencyName: "National Defense",
      agencyAddress: "24 Bauer Way<br>Menlo Park, CA 94025",
      phone: "(123) 242-4242",
      hireDate: "11-10-2008",
      has401k: false,
      lock: 1
    }
  ];

  // prepare the data
  var source = {
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [{
        name: "legalName"
      },
      {
        name: "agencyName"
      },
      {
        name: "agencyAddress"
      },
      {
        name: "phone"
      },
      {
        name: "hireDate",
        type: "date"
      },
      {
        name: "has401k",
        type: "bool"
      },
      {
        name: "lock",
        type: "number"
      }
    ],
    localdata: data
  };
  var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
  var source = {
    localdata: data,
    datatype: "array",
    loadComplete: function(data) {},
    loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {}
  };

  var editableNewRow = function(row, datafield, columntype) {
    var rowData = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);

    // return false to cancel edit as documented in columns > cellbeginedit
    return rowData.lock > 0 ? false : true;
  };

  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
    source: dataAdapter,
    sortable: true,
    theme: "energyblue",
    width: "98%",
    height: "630px",
    pageable: false,
    columnsresize: true,
    selectionMode: "none",
    filterable: true,
    showfilterrow: true,
    autoheight: true,
    autorowheight: true,
    groupable: true,
    editable: true,
    columns: [{
        text: "Legal Name",
        datafield: "legalName",
        width: "20%",
        cellbeginedit: editableNewRow
      },
      {
        text: "Agency Name",
        datafield: "agencyName",
        filtertype: "checkedlist",
        width: "20%",
        cellbeginedit: editableNewRow
      },
      {
        text: "Agency Address",
        datafield: "agencyAddress",
        width: "20%",
        cellbeginedit: editableNewRow
      },
      {
        text: "Phone",
        datafield: "phone",
        width: "20%",
        cellbeginedit: editableNewRow
      },
      {
        text: "Hire Date",
        datafield: "hireDate",
        cellsformat: "d",
        filtertype: "range",
        width: "10%",
        cellbeginedit: editableNewRow
      },
      {
        text: "Has 401K",
        datafield: "has401k",
        width: "10%",
        columntype: "checkbox",
        filtertype: "checkedlist",
        cellbeginedit: editableNewRow
      }
    ]
  });

  // $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('hidecolumn', 'legalName');
});

$("#addrowbutton").jqxButton({
  theme: "energyblue",
  height: 30
});

$("#addrowbutton").on("click", function() {
  var commit = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid("addrow", null, {
    editable: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqwidgets/14.0.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div id="jqxWidget">
  <header>
    <h2 class="text-center">Example: How to change <code>something here</code></h2>
  </header>
  <div id="jqxgrid" class="auto-margin"></div>
</div>
<p class="notice"><strong>*All data is test data only.</strong></p>

<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <input id="addrowbutton" type="button" value="Add Row" />
</div>
```